# Can't rename old dataset and import/upload new one with the original name: Skipping Ghost Tables linking

Tags: python, carto

I'm trying to run a script that renames the existing carto dataset to {CARTO_DATASET_NAME}_previous and then uses the import api to upload a file with the original name {CARTO_DATASET_NAME}. The problem with this is that the new imported file isn't created with {CARTO_DATASET_NAME} as desired, it's in fact created with a {CARTO_DATASET_NAME}_1 dataset name.

This is what I do to rename the dataset:

```
query = f'ALTER TABLE {CARTO_RAW_TABLE} RENAME to {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_prev;'
req_url = f'{CARTO_URL}/user/{CARTO_USER}/api/v2/sql?q={query}&api_key={CARTO_API_KEY}'
res = rq.get(req_url)
```

The response returns this text

```
Invalidation service configuration not found. Skipping Ghost Tables linking.'], 'notices': ['_CDB_LinkGhostTables() called with username=dev, event_name=ALTER TABLE']
```

As I previously said after renaming the original dataset, then I upload the new one:

```
upload_url = f'{CARTO_URL}/user/{CARTO_USER}/api/v1/imports/?api_key={CARTO_API_KEY}'

with open(csv_fname,'rb') as file_:
    try:
        res = rq.post(url = upload_url, verify = False,  files = {'file': file_})
    except TimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError("Error uploading csv file to carto")
    else:
        print('started uploading raw dataset to carto...')
```

I guess there's some problem when renaming the original dataset and it still exists with the original name, the ALTER TABLE clause not having the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to avoid renaming tables when dealing with ETL processes. Internally CARTO must have its own procedures to keep track of the tables and the `ALTER TABLE` statement must have been restricted.

I would suggest you to switch your mindset with this task:

First performa a:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_prev;
CREATE TABLE {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_prev AS
TABLE {CARTO_RAW_TABLE};
```

Then use the Import API to upload the file, don't forget to force the name to have a `_new` suffix. If not, CARTO will add the `_1, _2, ...` suffix.

You will need to "import" again from `{CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_new` to `CARTO_RAW_TABLE`. Like so.

```
DELETE {CARTO_RAW_TABLE};
INSERT INTO {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}
SELECT * FROM {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_new;
DROP TABLE {CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_new; -- Important if not, when importing the file again it would have the `_new_1` suffix
```

With this approach you will end up having 2 tables: `{CARTO_RAW_TABLE}` with new data coming from the Import API file table, and `{CARTO_RAW_TABLE}_prev` with the previous data.